# Calculate time elapsed taken by each command in real time like a stopwatch

Tags: bash, for

I have a script to do a lot of stuff, for example:

```
echo -e " finding mp3 files"
find / *.mp3
Elapsed time: 0
```

Assume this took 10 seconds.

A function to copy them to some location (this only an example, not my actual script):

```
echo copying files;
cp *.mp3 /
elapsed time: 6
```

I need a way to calculate and show a running clock while `find` finds all files, and after that to reset and show a new running clock while `cp` copies the files.

I tried this:

```
Timing () {
SECONDS=0; while true do;
printf '\e[1;96mElapsed Time: %dm:%ds\e[0m\n' $(($SECONDS%3600/60)) $(($SECONDS%60))
done &
}
```

and then call this function when doing the command.

However, I can’t reset the time and I cannot exit this background `while` loop.

Here is the full script that I want to add the timing function to:

```
#!/bin/bash

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#                  Modify to Match your Environment                              #
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

#enter managed servers names  STARTING ORDER  seperated by 'space'
#COMPNENTS Y or N in CAPS litters 

MANAGED_SERVERS_NAMES="WLS_FORMS WLS_REPORTS"
NODEMANAGER_SCRIPT_LOCATION="$WLS_HOME"/server/bin/startNodeManager.sh 
DOMAIN_ENV_LOCATION="$DOMAIN_HOME"/bin/setDomainEnv.sh
ADMINSERVER_SCRIPT_LOCATION="$DOMAIN_HOME"/bin/startWebLogic.sh
MANAGED_SERVERS_SCRIP_LOCATION="$DOMAIN_HOME"/bin/startManagedWebLogic.sh
OPMNCTL_COMPONENTS=Y
EMCTL_COMPONENT=Y


################################################################################
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#           This Script Is A CopyRight To KhaLiD Abo EL MaGd                     #
#                  Don't Modify Any Thing in This Section                        #
#                                                                                #
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
set -e
clear
TFILE=starting.log
debug=$1
if [[ -n "$debug" ]]; then
cat /dev/null > ${TFILE}
gnome-terminal  -e  "tail -F $TFILE" &
fi

Check_Status_NM ()
{
tail -f ${TFILE} | while read LOGLINE
do
    if [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"Secure socket listener started on port"* ]] 
    then
    echo -e "\e[92mNodeManager Started\e[0m"
    pkill -P $$ tail
    break
    elif [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"Address already in use"*  ]]; then
    pkill -P $$ tail
    echo -e "Cannot Start NodeManager\nSee ${TFILE} for more info\n "
  printf '\e[1;96mElapsed Time: %dm:%ds\e[0m\n' $(($SECONDS%3600/60)) $(($SECONDS%60))
  echo ""
  echo "$SECONDS" > time
    exit 1
    nohup kill -9 `ps -ef | grep ${TFILE} | awk '{print $2}'`  > /dev/null 2>&1 &
    echo "Total Time: $(cat time |   paste -sd+ |  bc)s"
    rm -rf time
    fi
done
}
#----------------------------------------------------------------
Check_Status ()
{
sleep 2
tail -F ${TFILE} | while read LOGLINE
do
  if [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"<Server state changed to STANDBY>"* ]]; then
    echo -e "\e[94mServer state changed to STANDBY\e[0m"
  elif  [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"<Server state changed to >"* ]]; then
      echo -e "\e[94mServer state changed to ADMIN\e[0m"
  elif [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"<Server state changed to RESUMING>"* ]]; then
     echo -e "\e[94mServer state changed to RESUMING\e[0m"
  elif  [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"<Server state changed to STARTING>"* ]]; then
      echo -e "\e[94mServer state changed to STARTING\e[0m"


    elif [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"The Network Adapter could not establish the connection"* ]] ; then
    echo -e "\e[5m\e[93mWARNING\e[0m Could not establish the connection\n\e[91mCheck Connection to Database\e[0m"
   elif  [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"<Server state changed to STARTING>"* ]]; then
      echo -e "\e[94mServer state changed to RUNNING\e[0m"
    elif [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"<Server started in RUNNING mode>"* ]] || [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"<Demo trusted CA certificate is being used in production mode:"* ]];then
    echo -e "\e[92mServer Started\e[0m"
      pkill -P $$ tail
    cat /dev/null > ${TFILE}
    break
    elif [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"<Server state changed to FORCE_SHUTTING_DOWN>"* ]]; then
      pkill -P $$ tail
     echo -e "\e[91mCannot Start Server\e[0m\nSee ${TFILE} for more info\n"
    printf '\e[1;96mElapsed Time: %dm:%ds\e[0m\n' $(($SECONDS%3600/60)) $(($SECONDS%60))
    echo ""
   echo "$SECONDS" >> time
    nohup kill -9 `ps -ef | grep ${TFILE} | awk '{print $2}'`  > /dev/null 2>&1 &
    echo "Total Time: $(cat time |   paste -sd+ |  bc)s"
    rm -rf time
    exit 1
    fi
done
}
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Start NodeManager:
SECONDS=0
echo -e "Starting NodeManager..."
nohup "$NODEMANAGER_SCRIPT_LOCATION"  > ${TFILE}  2>&1 &
 Timing ******************
Check_Status_NM
printf '\e[1;96mElapsed Time: %dm:%ds\e[0m\n' $(($SECONDS%3600/60)) $(($SECONDS%60))
echo ""
echo "$SECONDS" >> time
#Start WebLogic AdminServer------------------------------------------------
SECONDS=0
echo -e "Starting AdminServer..." 
nohup "$DOMAIN_ENV_LOCATION" > ${TFILE}   2> /dev/null &
 Timing ********************
nohup  > ${TFILE} "$ADMINSERVER_SCRIPT_LOCATION"  2> /dev/null &
Check_Status
printf '\e[1;96mElapsed Time: %dm:%ds\e[0m\n' $(($SECONDS%3600/60)) $(($SECONDS%60))
echo ""
echo "$SECONDS" >> time
#----------- MANAGED SERVERS------------------------------
for i in ${MANAGED_SERVERS_NAMES}
do
SECONDS=0
echo "Starting $i Server..."
nohup ${MANAGED_SERVERS_SCRIP_LOCATION} $i  > ${TFILE}  2> /dev/null &
Check_Status
printf '\e[1;96mElapsed Time: %dm:%ds\e[0m\n' $(($SECONDS%3600/60)) $(($SECONDS%60))
echo ""
echo "$SECONDS" >> time
done
nohup kill -9 `ps -ef | grep ${TFILE} | awk '{print $2}'`  > /dev/null 2>&1 &

#--------------------- OPMNCTL------------------------
if [[ "${OPMNCTL_COMPONENTS}" == *"Y"* ]]; then
SECONDS=0
echo -e "Starting opmn components"
nohup opmnctl startall > /dev/null 2>&1 &
sleep 2
if ( opmnctl status |grep --quiet Init); then
echo -e "\e[94mWaiting For opmn components to Start\e[0m"
opmnctl status |grep -v --quiet Init
opm_pid=$!
while [ -d /proc/$opm_pid ]; do
    echo -n "."
    sleep 2
done
else
echo -e "\e[92mStarted\e[0m" 
fi
opmnctl status | grep -v Alive
printf '\e[1;96mElapsed Time: %dm:%ds\e[0m\n' $(($SECONDS%3600/60)) $(($SECONDS%60))
echo ""
echo "$SECONDS" >> time
fi
#---------------------EMCTL-----------------------------------
if [[ "${EMCTL_COMPONENT}" == *"Y"* ]]; then
SECONDS=0
emctl start agent
printf '\e[1;96mElapsed Time: %dm:%ds\e[0m\n' $(($SECONDS%3600/60)) $(($SECONDS%60))
echo ""
echo "$SECONDS" >> time
fi
#-----------------------------------------------------------
TIMEE=$(cat time |   paste -sd+ |  bc)
echo ""
printf '\e[1;96mTotal Time: %dm:%ds\e[0m\n'  $(($TIMEE%3600/60)) $(($TIMEE%60))
cat /dev/null > time
exit 0
```

i was able to mostly get what i want by doing this based on answers
but i want to know how to kill the while loop in Check_Status function after it prints server started or Cannot Start Server

```
echo -e "Starting AdminServer..." 
nohup "$DOMAIN_ENV_LOCATION" > ${TFILE}   2> /dev/null &
START_TIME=$(date +%s)
nohup  > ${TFILE} "$ADMINSERVER_SCRIPT_LOCATION"  2> /dev/null &
Check_Status &
while [[ -d /proc/$! ]]; do
SECONDS=$(( $(date +%s)-START_TIME ))
 printf "\e[1;96mElapsed Time: %02dm:%02ds\e[0m\r" $(($SECONDS%3600/60))     $(($SECONDS%60))
done
printf "\e[1;96mElapsed Time: %dm:%ds\e[0m\n" $(($SECONDS%3600/60))    $(($SECONDS%60))
echo "$SECONDS" >> time
```

Comment: What's wrong with `time`? E.g. `time sleep 3` should show the elapsed time, along with other values.

Comment: i don't need a sleep time ..as the main script go to search for some words in log files and if it found exact word it gives my the status of the server

Comment: also i cannot kill the background loop

Comment: I understand you want bash for this, but just as a suggestion, you might wanna look at some languages that might make it easier. For example, Perl : my $sttime = time;
sleep(60);
print "Elapsed time : ", time - $sttime;

Comment: thank you for your reply..i have no idea about perl.. and i still need my original script in bash as it runs some oracle services ....

Comment: Could you please edit the question to clarify what you want to output, exactly? The time taken by a single command (or a set of commands) after it finishes? Times for single commands plus a total? A counter running up every second? You may want to consider making the example code a bit shorter and to the point.

Comment: (Also, please don't write in ALL CAPS, it looks like you're yelling and is consider rude.)

Comment: Do you realize that such a command will use 100% of a CPU core for absolutely nothing?

Comment: No i didn't..thank you for your comment

Answer (score 4):

This one shows the time when it is done:

```
#! /bin/bash
START_TIME=$(date +%s)
echo -n Finding mp3 files
sleep 3 # some time consuming command
echo .\ Elapsed time: $(( $(date +%s)-START_TIME ))
```

It will respond:

```
Finding mp3 files
```

and then

```
Finding mp3 files. Elapsed time: 3
```

---

If you want to see the time counting up while waiting, the time consuming command must not echo anything (of course).

```
#! /bin/bash
START_TIME=$( date +%s )
echo Finding mp3 files
sleep 3 & # some time consuming command
while [[ -d /proc/$! ]]; do
    echo -en \\rElapsed time: $(( $(date +%s)-START_TIME ))
    sleep 0.1
done
echo .
```

Explanation: When the command goes in the background with `&` it leaves the process id number in `$!`. This process is represented by a (virtual) directory in `/proc/$!`. As long as this directory exists, the command is running and we are counting up the time.

---

Third example; more like the question. Replace `sleep 3` with the time consuming command.

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Starting NodeManager..."
START_TIME=$(date +%s)
nohup sleep 3 &
while ps -p $! > /dev/null ; do
    SECONDS=$(( $(date +%s)-START_TIME ))
    printf "\r\e[1;96mElapsed Time: %02dm:%02ds\e[0m" $(($SECONDS%3600/60)) $(($SECONDS%60))
done
Echo
```

Edit: The third example now show [the right way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043978/how-to-check-if-a-process-id-pid-exists) to test for a process is still running. (but it has to launch a process `ps` and thus it is slower - your choice)

Comment: thank you ...but the command echo some information about the status of the server which it take it from the log.... 
i need something like wget or scp it echo data and gives elapsed time

Comment: That is what the first example shows.

Comment: i tried it but it just echo one time as i put it as a function and call it ..
here is the code

     Timing ()
      {
    START_TIME=$(date +%s)
    sleep 1
    echo .\ Elapsed time: $(( $(date +%s)-START_TIME ))
   }
  

    #Start NodeManager:
    echo -e "Starting NodeManager..."
    nohup "$NODEMANAGER_SCRIPT_LOCATION"  > ${TFILE}  2>&1 &
   Timing
Check_Status_NM
printf "\e[1;96mElapsed Time: %dm:%ds\e[0m\n" $(($SECONDS%3600/60)) $(($SECONDS%60))
echo "$SECONDS" >> time



Starting NodeManager...
. Elapsed time: 1
NodeManager Started
Elapsed Time: 0m:3s

Comment: i also tried to put it as you showed but its not counting

Comment: Thank you again...but it doesn't work ..as it in first place i can't use sleep as the main function of the script is to go to the logs and find the stat of the server ..when it changes to running it go to the next server and start it ...in you example you missed the function (Check_Status_NM) that is do all the job of checking the status of the server till it become running ...again thank you very much

Comment: this is the output

Starting AdminServer...
Elapsed Time: 00m:01sServer state changed to STARTING

Comment: @hschou, it's probably worth pointing out that the `/proc/` filesystem is not present on all systems that have Bash.  It is available on most Linux systems, but is not a POSIX requirement (and who knows what's on Windows or MacOS?).  If you don't have `/proc`, you might be able to `kill -0 $!` or `ps -p$!` as a substitute test (with the usual caveats).

Comment: Another tip: if the child process *might* produce output, you can put the `\r` at the end of the `printf`, so that the output will likely just overwrite the current timer value and leave the cursor at the start of the next line.  Remember to output `\n` after the `while` loop, of course.

Comment: the /proc is exist

Comment: i tried kill -0 $! or ps -p$! in the check_status function after echo server started but with no luck

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pv`](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml):

```
sleep 10 | pv -t

find / -name '*.mp3' | pv -t
```

`pv` is a pass-through like `cat` (sometimes even more efficient as it uses system calls like `splice()` where possible), that writes the timing information on stderr.

If you want to display `Elapsed time:` as well:

```
pv -N 'Elapsed time' -t
```

or (with newer versions):

```
pv -F 'Elapsed time: %t'
```

If using `zsh`, `ksh` or `bash`, you may want want to set the `pipefail` option to not lose the exit status of the command being monitored:

```
timewatch() (
  set -o pipefail
  "$@" | pv -tN 'Elapsed time'
)

timewatch find / -name '*.mp3' || handle_error
```